# How to convert RGB values to Hexidecimal values using System.out.printf() statement in Java

Tags: java, rgb, hex

I have to convert RGB color code into hexadecimal code in my java program, and I'm not sure how to do that. I'm supposed to use the System.out.printf() statement to do the conversion.

Could anyone show me an example of how to do this in Java? I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: What's an "RGB color code"? Is it three bytes, three ints, an array or bytes packed into an int? Please show us some code.

Comment: Sorry. It's three ints. So I have "rgb(13,139,214)," and I need to convert that into hexadecimal format.

Answer (score 5):

I think you're just asking how to take a triplet of decimal integers, e.g. `rgb(0, 100, 255)` and convert it into a single hex string like they use in HTML, e.g. `#0064FF`. I'd use [`printf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Console.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) instead of `println`:

```
System.out.printf("#%02X%02X%02X%n", red, green, blue);
```

If you're really set on using `println`, then you can use `String.format` for the conversion:

```
System.out.println(String.format("#%02X%02X%02X", red, green, blue));
```

If you want to understand how it works, you can read up on [Java's Format String Syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax). Basically, `%02X` means: print an `int` as a two-digit upper-case hexadecimal number, padding with zeros if necessary. They also recommend using `%n` instead of `\n` for the newline at the end of the string since it's more platform-independent (it gets translated to `\r\n` on Windows).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways to do this.  Here are a few ideas.

If you `ALWAYS` want the object to show the hex value when printed override your `toString()` so that it gives you the correct output.   This is not optimal...  What if you decide in the future your `toString()` needs to do something different?

A better way would be to add a `public String asHex()` method  that way its always clear what your doing.  Then you can:

```
System.out.println(new rgb(0, 0, 0).asHex());
```

And you would see a  #000000